# What is the best way to pull params from this post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, attributes, parameters

There is probably a better way to accomplish this.

I click on this button of 7 different buttons ( each for each day of the week ) in a form..

```
= radio_button_tag 'days_gift_available', '{:monday => true}', true, {:class => "live-form"}
```

Then when the form is sent, I get this in my params..

```
"{:monday => true}"
```

And here's where I'm confused.. I want to take this data and apply it like so :

```
                  This is supposed to be a dynamic var for the day.
                                         |
                                         |
                                         V
  if @organization.days_gift_available[:day] == false || @organization.days_gift_available[:day] == nil
    @organization.days_gift_available = {:day => true}
  else
    @organization.days_gift_available = {:day => false}
  end
```

**notice my awful failing attempt  at using the variable for the `[:day]` attribute. Not really sure how to apply that either..**

My question is, how do I pull this hash data and apply it in an update_attribute call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How radio buttons work:

All radio buttons of a certain group have the same name BUT different values. Only the value of the checked radio button gets submitted.

```
- # monday
= radio_button_tag 'days_gift_available', '1', true, {:class => "live-form"}
- # tuesday 
= radio_button_tag 'days_gift_available', '2', false, {:class => "live-form"}
- # thursday
= radio_button_tag 'days_gift_available', '3', false, {:class => "live-form"}
- # ...until sunday
```

in your controller:

```
@organization.days_gift_available = params[:days_gift_available]
```

`params[:days_gift_available]` is the selected day and should lie in the range from 1 to 7